# Dynamic SQL - why variable stays empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have problem with dynamic sql (yeah only one ;) )

Inside stored procedure I declared a local variable like this :

DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max)
Later in the code I have this line with a lots of input parameters my sp recieved (sorry for the mess didn't succeed in organizing it) :

```
SET @cmd = 'INSERT INTO dbo.' + @ArchiveTableName + '(' + @ArchiveFieldsName + ',' + @ArchiveEntityMainIdentifierField + ')
    SELECT ' + @EntityFieldsName + ',' + '' + @EntityMainIdentifierField + '' +
       ' FROM [' + @OrganizationName + '].[dbo].[' + @EntityName + '] ent
        left join dbo.' + @ArchiveTableName + ' arc on arc.' + @ArchiveEntityMainIdentifierField + ' = ent.' + @EntityMainIdentifierField + '
        where ent.' + @EntityMainIdentifierField + ' = ''' + @ParentId + ''' and arc.' + @ArchiveEntityMainIdentifierField + ' is null'
```

After I debugged it, I found something weird. After running this @cmd stays empty.

Can anyone please give me a clue of why this might be happening?

Comment: If one `variable` is `NULL` then the entire string will become `NULL`

Comment: oh didnt know it , i will check it out now.

Comment: yep thats the thing , thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet one of your other variables is `NULL`. `'Something' + NULL = NULL`. You can use [CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)(sql server 2012+), it will turn `NULL` into an empty string. Better is to use [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)(sql server 2008+) as well (and make sure the essential variables aren't `NULL`).